# Proxy js object: where are defined arguments when calling a function using Reflect.get()

Tags: javascript, reflection, javascript-proxy

Trying to understand the internals of [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) built-in objects, I've reached - IMO - an interesting "*how does this even work*" point:

Let's say I want to wrap into a Proxy this object and detect when we're accessing a callable property:

```js
const obj = {
 v: 42,
 foo(n) { return this.v + n }
}
```

```js
const pObj = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop, r) {
    if (typeof target[prop] === 'function') {
      console.log('accessing a function, arguments: ', { ...arguments })
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
})
```

This code just works:

```
pObj.foo(1000) // « 1042
```

Printing this trace:

[image: trace when calling the function]

Which reads: `arguments` has

- target (`[0]`): the object
- prop (`[1]`): `"foo"`
- receiver (`[2]`): the proxy object itself.

My question is, **where is defined the function argument (`1000`) that is applied to `foo(n)`?** isn't defined in `arguments`? is it possible to validate this argument before calling `Reflect.get(...arguments)`?

Comment: You're reading the `arguments` to `get`, so it shouldn't be surprising that the arguments match those passed to `get`. I would think you'd want to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) to handle a function call though.

Comment: my point is `Reflect.get()` does call `foo(1000)` with no problems. How? Where does `1000` come from?

Comment: Because `Proxy.get` is passed enough information through its arguments to allow `Reflect.get` to do its job. But you ask "Is it possible to validate this argument" and I'm saying, that's going to be a lot easier with `apply`, considering it is passed a list of arguments to the function it wraps. If you don't want that kind of practical help (using the right tool for the job), explicitly state your purpose (which could be curiosity).

Comment: Your `get` trap executes due to the property access of `.foo` on `pObj` when you do `pObj.foo`, and not because you're calling `.foo(...)`. The `Reflect.get()` doesn't call `foo(1000)`, it returns a function (`obj.foo`), that's being invoked by `(1000)` in your original calling code outside of the proxy handler.

Comment: thanks @NickParsons, if you reply to answer I could accept this